# Get string value in Android

Tags: java, android, string

There are some string resources in my android application and some helper-classes, which are only java-classes (no android classes).

Is it possible to get string value of string resource variable from an java class?!

Mur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Context to access any resource string value. It can be either an activity context or the Application context.